# Upload remote files to my server via user's computer

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

I am trying to upload remote files to my server. I can do this with my remote url upload script which is simple and it is working. But I want to use it in a different way.

In the general upload script we use

```
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="content" />
```

So in this case we are manually browsing the files from the user's computer and uploading. I want to do the same with remote urls. When the user enters the remote url location I want to convert it to a local file and then upload. The benefit I am getting by converting remote files to local files before uploading is, I can check and use my existing codes which I use for local uploads.

The sequence I want is

- user inputs url location and just after the url is entered I want to trigger an `onmouseover` event which will fill this

  `<input type="file" id="myfile" name="content" />`
- and then I can process as usual.

Comment: I am not sure, that you can fill `input type="file"` using javascript (security reasons). Have you considered using flash?

Comment: If people set an URL in the Open File Dialog that opens when they browse the input type=file, windows will automatically download the file on their computer, and then it will be re-uploaded from their local computer to the server.

You must use a input type=text and read the url with `copy`or `file_get_contents`or maybe `curl`I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payal,
Use a simple textbox (type=text) and allow user to paste the url directly on that box. Now use a `"onkeyup"` function on that textbox and call the upload script or basically submit the page..whatever process you want to follow for your upload.

```
<input type="text" name="fileurl" onkeyup="javascript:uploadTrigger()">

function uploadTrigger(){
// submit the form
// OR
// call ajax upload
}
```

Consider error validation. Thanks.

Comment: i have little doubt. i know we can do this but where the file is??? it is remote file so when i will trigger what will be inserted and how.please explain if u have idea very confused

Comment: If you have any specific file type (like doc/pdf/jpg), you can validate the file on the keyup function (like looking for .doc or .pdf in the string) and then use PHP "copy" function to copy the remote file into your local location and then process further. Hope it will help.

Comment: i have my validation script just i want to trigger and fill the form filled but how i dont know.if you can tell it will be a great help.just i want to fill the form filled but how to create temp file for that link.suppose i have http://lq.mzc.in/data48-2/37202/Appy_Budday_(Videshi)-Santokh_Singh(www.Mzc.in).mp3 then i want to create a temp file so that it can be uploaded in server .mp3 file is there but how to upload it i dont want to save that file manually to my desktop and upload.i want to create a temp file for that mp3 in server and upload it

Comment: Well, creating temp file is not your headache..it'll taken care by the server itself, check the php copy function and the examples (http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php). Pass the remote url and destination location in the command. Use localhost or local IP while uploading.

Comment: i am able to upload to server but how to pass remote file loacation in file type .if u can help please

Comment: Great payal, you should use remote file location as a url in the copy function, like.. copy( "hhttp://example.net/file.mp3" , "./local_file.mp3" );

Comment: can u give the code for file type please how to do i am not getting thanks for your helpadd me plz http://www.facebook.com/cutepayalmalhotra